# Instant content update on AJAX submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an form submit function that sends an AJAX requeest in a JS file, and another file that renders data received from the database. What I am trying to achieve is the following: when a user has updated the content/image while previewing it, it automatically updates. Currently, upon update, the content does not update, unless re-selecting the `<div>` to see updated information.

I have tried using the `.load()` function within the AJAX submit, detecting the preview panel is displayed and refreshing content.

**AJAX submit function:**

```js
("#userForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit
    
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements
        success: function(data) {
            // if the preview div is displayed refresh div
            if ($(".preview-panel")[0]) {  
                $(".inner-edit").load(" .inner-edit > *"); // update the div class
            }
            alert(data); // show response from the php script
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `$(".inner-edit").html(data);`? Because `.load()` expects a URL.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi the html returned is {"success":true,"result":null,"error":null}.

Comment: What HTML? Do you mean the `data` parameter of the success function?